# Variable Tip Calculator Inputs

Tags: python, variables, input, python-3.7

I am trying to create a tip calculator like every other newbie and of course I ran in to a problem. Most of the code works fine, but I can't figure out how to take user input for the tip and incorporate it into the grand total.

This page was a good resource and told me that I need to point python in the direction to interpret the input as math used in the solution. I wasn't able to translate it in my head into my code though.

[Tip Calculator Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038373/tip-calculator-function-in-python)

```
# Tip Calculator
import random
bill = input("How much was your bill? ")
x = float(bill)
tip10 = x * .10
tip15 = x * .15

tip20 = x * .20

tip10 = float(tip10)
tip15 = float(tip15)
tip20 = float(tip20)

total = x + tip10
total = x + tip15
total = x + tip20
print(f"If you would like to leave a 10%, the tip amount will be ${tip10}.")
print(f"If you would like to leave a 15%, the tip amount will be ${tip15}.")
print(f"If you would like to leave a 20%, the tip amount will be ${tip20}.")
input("How much tip would you like to leave? ")
print(f"Your total is ${total:.2f}.)
```

When I run this it is only giving me the `tip20` result after asking how much tip to leave, which I finally figured out is because it is the last line of the totals.

How can I incorporate the user input into the total for the last line of code?

Comment: You need to learn about `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real need to hard-code each tip.

```
# Tip Calculator
import random
bill = input("How much was your bill? ")
x = float(bill)
example_tips = [10, 15, 20]

for tip in example_tips:
    print(f"If you would like to leave a {tip}%, the tip amount will be ${x*tip/100}}.")
choice = input("How much tip would you like to leave? ")
total = x*(1+float(choice)/100)
print(f"Your total is ${total:.2f}.)
```

Here, `choice` is intended to be a percentage as in `example_tips`.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user for input again, and then calculate `total` based on what they say.

```
tipAmount = input("How much tip would you like to leave? (10, 15, 20) ")
if tipAmount == "10":
    total = x + tip10
elif tipAmount == "15":
    total = x + tip15
elif tipAmount == "20":
    total = x + tip20
else:
    total = x
    print("You're not leaving a tip? You cheapskate.")
print(f"Your total is ${total:.2f}")
```

I'll leave the problem of making sure the user input is one of those three options as an exercise to the reader (if you get stuck, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)).

Comment: While I realise it's just an example, the print message in the blanket else statement might not be cool if the user is feeling overly generous and enters something like 50.

Comment: @aadibajpai Motivation to check the input and handle it dynamically!

Answer (score 0):

`input("How much tip would you like to leave? ")` doesn't output to a variable.

Also, `total = x + tip20` is the only statement that has effect on `total`. What you'll want to do is to add the user input to the variable by changing this: `input("How much tip would you like to leave? ")` to this: `total = x + float(input("How much tip would you like to leave? "))`

Of course, this is if you want the tips you output to be a sort of suggestion for the user. If you want for the user to use your values, you're better off using Green Cloak Guy's answer.

Comment: You'd need to case `input()` to a `float` before this would work. Otherwise you get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: i fixed the answer @GreenCloakGuy